# Python how to sum new value to existing one?

Tags: python

Text file contains:

```
Matt 25
Matt 22
John 1
John 2
John 5
```

And I'm trying to calculate their total points with this but now it just adds the number to value and doesn't sum it:

```
filename = input("Enter the name of the score file: ")

file = open(filename, mode="r")
print("Contestant score:")

score = dict()

for file_line in sorted(file):

    file_line = file_line.split()
    if file_line[0] in score:
        score[file_line[0]] += file_line[1]
    else:
        score[file_line[0]] = file_line[1]

print(score)

file.close()
```

But print is : {'Matt': '2525', 'John': '125'}

instead of:
{'Matt': '50', 'John': '8'}

Comment: You need to convert them to integers first, it treats them as strings now and just concatenates them

Comment: U summing string, you need to cast them to int first

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change it to

```py
    if file_line[0] in score:
        score[file_line[0]] += int(file_line[1])
    else:
        score[file_line[0]] = int(file_line[1])
```

`file_line[1]` is a string, so using the `+=` operator just appends to the string instead of performing mathematic addition.

Comment: Yes I did, I had to just wait 10 minutes to do so.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are doing the operation with strings and not integers, so you are concatenating them instead of adding the values they represent. To fix that add a call to int in both conditions:

```
score[file_line[0]] = int(file_line[1])
```

and:

```
score[file_line[0]] += int(file_line[1])
```

Comment: You are correct. Edited my answer to make clear int must be called twice.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the values to integers:

```
filename = input("Enter the name of the score file: ")

file = open(filename, mode="r")
print("Contestant score:")

score = dict()

for file_line in sorted(file):

    file_line = file_line.split()
    if file_line[0] in score:
        score[file_line[0]] += int(file_line[1]) #convert to int
    else:
        score[file_line[0]] = int(file_line[1]) #convert to int

print(score)

file.close()
```